# What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, pronunciation-vs-spelling, saxon-genitive

What is the possessive of a noun ending in *‑s*?  Are these both right, or is the second one wrong?

1. the boys' books
2. the boss' car

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Your example sentences confuse two different problems.

For nouns that are plural (such as "boys"), the possessive is formed in writing by adding an apostrophe after the plural *-s*. This is pronounced the same as the plural and the singular possessive:

> The boys' books [*boys'* sounds like *boys*]

For singular nouns that end in *-s*, the possessive is formed by adding *-'s*, just as with other nouns. This is pronounced as if the spelling were *es*:

> The boss's car [*boss's* sounds like *bosses*]

There is a partial exception for proper names that end in *s*. These names sometimes form their possessive by simply adding an apostrophe, and without changing their pronunciation:

> Confucius' sayings
>
> Jesus' teachings

However, this doesn't apply if the name ends with a letter other than *s*, even if it's pronounced with an *s*. These names form their possessive as normal:

> Marx's theories

In the opposite case of a name which ends in a silent *s*, the possessive is usually formed by adding an apostrophe in writing, but the apostrophe causes the silent *s* to be pronounced:

> Camus' novels [the final *-s* in *Camus* is not silent here]

Comment: +1, I hadn't thought about the implications of the proper name exception when used with a silent final s.

Comment: +1, but I'll note that there exist style guides which follow the following simplistic rule: if a singular noun ends with an s, just add “'s”, regardless of whether it's a proper noun or how it's pronounced. I like the simplicity of this rule.

Comment: Do you have a source on this with proper names not needing an extra s?  I am fairly certain it should still be Confucius's sayings, Jesus's teachings, and Camus's novels, with the first s still silent in the last case.

Comment: @StrixVaria: Absolutely. Many speakers would (albeit with misgivings, before and/or after vocalisation) enunciate the third **s** for Jesus's possessions. I venture to suggest virtually *no-one* would try that with *mistresses's*... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22978/how-do-i-pronounce-ss-and-s/22987#22987

Comment: There are special cases for biblical and classical names , so it's "Dickens' writings" but  Jesus' and Moses' or Achilles'

Comment: @FumbleFingers But "mistresses" is already plural and wouldn't get the extra s after the apostrophe anyway.

Comment: @StrixVaria: Yes. I didn't register that when I wrote it, but you're right. I think we *never* enunciate the possessive s on plurals made by adding s. It's just the *Jesus's* one that might or might not. I'm not a preacher so I wouldn't talk much about him anyway. But if I did, I'd probably stop saying the s there fairly soon.

Comment: @JSBangs: re *partial exception for proper names that end in -s*, it seems to me the only cases where this applies is if there's a *preceding* 's' or similar before the last one. And I think there's uncertainty over whether the possessive is enunciated or not, which has no connection with whether it's *written* or not. And this NGram shows it *is* written sometimes... http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Jesus%27s%2CJesus%27&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: In light of which, note that in the case of *Camus'* the possessive s is written as often as not. It may be an irrelevancy of perspective, but I suggest it's not that *the apostrophe causes the silent s to be pronounced*. That one remains silent. It's the possessive s that *always* gets enunciated by people saying *Camus'*, even if reading aloud from a text that happens not to include it in written form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it's tricky. I would definitely add an "s", when speaking, to any word that doesn't already sound like it's a plural (so *Jesus's*, *Chaz's*, etc. -- Chaz because English words can't end with /æ/). But I would not add an "s" to Achilles, which already sounds like an English plural (and since nobody talks about Achilles's heel, I think this is fairly common). And I don't think anybody says *Moses's.* On the other hand, *Rose* sounds like the English plural *rows*, and I would definitely say *Rose's*. But I would probably also say *Loews'*, and *Loews* rhymes with *Rose*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: very interesting examples. I think *Jesus's* is a cusp point, and may or may not get the possessive enunciated. All others I'm 100% same as you except maybe *Loews'* where I'm unsure (but so are you lol). But I think maybe others differ, and maybe neither we personally, not any gramarian, can lay down the law about exactly when you *shouldn't* sound that extra 's'. The most interesting thing to me so far is that enunciation isn't necessarily dictated by orthography - in some cases you can say or nor, and write or not.

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references?  I'm not asking because I don't believe you.  I'm asking because when the question comes up I can't say "because some guy on the internet said so", not even if said guy got 60 upvotes.

Comment: This is an answer worthy of being canonical for questions about possessives. I second @Szabolcs'(s) comment and request, particularly for the case involving the *boss's car*.

Comment: Too many exceptions to the rule. English is broken.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what about **Descartes** /deɪˈkɑːrt/ ? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/

Comment: @GJC: Personally I'd write [***Descartes’s name***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Descartes%E2%80%99+name%2CDescartes%E2%80%99s+name&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) rather than ***Descartes’ name*** (both occur, as that NGram link shows) But we're a long way from the "real English language" by then, since I consider *all* language to be essentially *spoken* rather than written. On top of which ***Descartes*** is a French proper noun with a phonologically irrelevant trailing /s/ - it's not even English in the first place (as with JSBձոգչ's *Camus* above).

Comment: @FumbleFingers According to LPD, "With proper names ending in a sibilant, usage varies. Usually, the possessive is pronounced regularly, though the spelling may vary: _Jones’ , Jones’s_ **dʒoʊnzəz**. Less commonly, the possessive ending is unpronounced (**dʒoʊnz**), but the corresponding spelling is then _Jones’_  "

Comment: @GJC: If LPD (Longman's Pronunciation Dictionary?) are implying there's a strong connection between whether the final possessive ***s***  is *articulated* and whether it's *transcribed* or not, I think that's misleading. I don't think the orthography itself makes a blind bit of difference to whether people articulate one or two ***s's*** in something like *Saint **James's / James'** Park*. Some people pronounce it and some don't, just as some write it and some don't. But at the end of the day there's only one "language", for which both orthographies are just "approximations".

Comment: (Mind you, *Saint **Jamesiz** Park* notwithstanding, I can say with some conviction that I've never heard - and never *expect* to hear - any references to *Davey **Jonesiz** Locker*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers what about **your guys'(s)**? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_guys#Usage_notes

Comment: Spotted in a NYT daily news briefing: "But Biden’s policy stops short of minimizing the virus’s spread."

Comment: What about the possessive form of "chassis"? It's not a proper noun, but it does end in a silent "s". On its own I pronounce it "shassy". In possessive form, is it then "chassis's" (as in "the chassis's connected peripherals"), and pronounced "shassy's"? The rules in the answer don't appear to extend to cover (a) non-proper nouns ending in silent "s" and (b) foreign borrow-words (i.e. do we borrow the possessive form from the target language as well, or apply English's rules?).

Answer (score 18):

On singular nouns that end with an "s" or "z" sound, [Wikipedia has a say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Singular_nouns_ending_with_an_.E2.80.9Cs.E2.80.9D_or_.E2.80.9Cz.E2.80.9D_sound). According to the article, there is no hard and fast rule on this one and different "authorities" prefer different styles.

See also [St. James's park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._James%27s_Park) and [St. James' park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_James%27_Park).

Answer (score 1):

On the use of so-called 'zero genitive', marked by a simple apostrophe in spelling ('), and the *'s* possessive with nouns ending with an *s*, Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech and Svartvik specify in *A Comprehensive grammar of the English Language* (pp. 320 & 321) that:

> In addition to its normal use with regular plurals such as *boys'*, the 'zero genitive' is used to avoid repetitive or awkward combinations of sounds in the following cases:
>
> (i) with Greek names of more than one syllable that end in *-s*, as in:
>
> *Euripides'* /di:z/ plays, *Xerxes'* army, *Socrates'* wife
>
> (ii) with many other names ending in /z/, where in speech zero is a variant of the regular /ɪz/ genitive.  There is vacillation both in the pronunciation and in the spelling of these names, but most commonly the pronunciation is /ɪz/, and the spelling is an apostrophe only.  (In the following examples, the minority form is given in parentheses.)
>
> WRITTEN FORMS
>
> *Burns'* (*Burns's*) poem
>
> *Dickens'* (*Dickens's*) novels
>
> *Jones'* (*Jones's*) car
>
> SPOKEN FORMS
>
> /ˈbɜ:nzɪz (bɜ:nz)/
>
> /ˈdɪkɪnzɪz (ˈdɪkɪnz)/
>
> /ˈdʒəunzɪz (dʒəunz)/
>
> Names ending in other sibilants than /z/ have the regular /ɪz/ genitive: *Ross's* /ˈrɒsɪz/ *theories*.  However, *Jesus* and *Moses*  normally have the zero form of the spoken genitive, /ˈdʒi:zəs/ and /ˈməuzɪz/, and are written *Jesus'* and *Moses'* (as well as *Jesus's* and *Moses's*).
>
> (iii) with fixed expression of the form *for* . . . *sake*, as in *for goddness' sake*, *for conscience' sake*, where the noun ends in /s/.

*Boss* ends in a sibilant, /s/, other than /z/, and becomes *boss's* in the possessive.  So we have *the boss's car*.

Comment: What corpora did Quirk et al use? [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Burns%27+poems%2CBurns%27s+poems&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBurns%20%27%20poems%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBurns%20%27s%20poems%3B%2Cc0) seem to strongly suggest that Burns' is the minority form. If I'm reading them correctly. / tchrist has answered elsewhere that 's and the /ɪz/ pronunciation are almost always twinned.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The list of abbreviations and symbols has SEU which stands for Survey of English Usage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_of_English_Usage) founded by Quirk himself in the late fifties at UCL.  I agree that the 's forms form Burns, Dickens, Wells and similar names feel intuitively more widespread.  Perhaps Quirk et al.'s remark is more prescriptive than descriptive.

Comment: Hmm, he's/they're usually pretty good. // I came across something giving a rule-of-thumb ('Truss', I think) that usages 'concerning antiquities' tended not to add the second s while more modern examples did (or vice versa). I wondered if this licensed _Athens' glory days were millenia ago; Athens's more recent history may not be so well known_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According to Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, "With proper names ending in a sibilant, usage varies. Usually, the possessive is pronounced regularly, though the spelling may vary: _Jones’ , Jones’s_ **dʒoʊnzəz**. Less commonly, the possessive ending is unpronounced (**dʒoʊnz**), but the corresponding spelling is then _Jones’_  "

Comment: @GJC Do they mention what research they've carried out? Certainly ACGEL (1985) must be out of date on this now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  what about **your guys'(s)**? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_guys#Usage_notes

Comment: @GJC Non-standard².