# When did it become correct to add an “s” to a singular possessive already ending in “‑s”?

Tags: orthography, history, possessives, apostrophe, proper-nouns

According to my grammar book, but at variance to the answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s), the correct singular possessive if a word ends in *‑s* is:

> James’s car

The grammar book allows exceptions for historical nouns, so the examples in the answer to the above-linked question would pass muster.

However, I’m sure that I learnt at school (which, admittedly, was a while ago) that for a singular (proper) noun ending in *‑s*, the apostrophe went after the *s* and there was no additional *s*.

I don’t wish to start a flame war on which is correct, though my question doesn't really make sense if my grammar book is wrong!  What I’m curious about is *when* the change occurred.  :

So my question is when did *James’s* become the correct form and *James’* the incorrect one?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Since, 1810, forms like *James’s* (which I will call type A) have generally been more commonly used than forms like *James’* (type B), [according to my research](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/?c=coha&q=6179109) using the Corpus of Historical American English (COHA).

I compared a number of names ending in *-s* looking for possessive forms with and without a final *s*. Here is a graph comparing incidences of type A and type B forms:

[image: graph showing forms with and without apostrophe since 1810].
The y-axis shows the difference in incidence between types A and B. If it is above 0, that means that type A was more common in that period; if below 0, that means type B was more common. The raw data used to generate the chart is in [this Google Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AkifeicKYWtgdGVsa2ZXSHEwSzBoakRrVHE4VWZwVVE&hl=en&single=true&gid=0&output=html).

Here’s the same data, shown cumulatively:[image: same data, shown cumulatively]

For the 14 names tested, type A has been more common throughout the period beginning in 1810, except for the decades starting in 1850, 1940, and 1950.

Overall, it is quite clear that type A forms (e.g. *James’s*) predominate, and have done so for nearly two hundred years. Nevertheless, type B forms are also quite common, and during the 1930s to the 1960s, a number of names had more incidences using type B. But since 1970, most names have had a majority of usage in type A. As for the original question’s example of *James*, throughout almost the entire period, excluding 1820, incidences of *James’s* has strongly outnumbered incidences of *James’*.

Comment: Amazing research and data representation.

Comment: COHA sounds like a place where one could seriously lose a few days!  Now if only there was a COHB as well.  As a die-hard Brit, I'd prefer evidence of usage in Britain, but I suspect that's a requirement too far so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Very nice answer. Btw, I just fixed a small typo: "181" to "1810"

Comment: Sorry to always be a naysayer, but I'm suspicious of the data being used here. Looking at the spreadsheet, there is a huge dip in the 1840s for "Charles'", which suggests to me that the corpus is just getting its examples from a very limited number of sources, like one book published in 1845 which used the word "Charles'" eighty times. That would make the results and graphs meaningless. Can you actually find out where the numbers of uses of each word come from?

Comment: @Shinto, yes the data is noisy. That’s why I looked at 14 different names. Take it with a grain of salt. In aggregate, though, there is enough of a trend to say something.

Comment: @Shinto I have come to count on you to be the naysayer where appropriate. You have always had valid points, but your tone is much improved, and I (and I assume others) appreciate that. Your point is valid that the data here is quite noisy because a particular usage gets a lot of hits because it is the name of a character in a work of fiction in the corpus. However, I think in aggregate the data is sufficient to show that type A is somewhat more common, though both types are used frequently.

Comment: Personally, I have always written `Ross'` because it seems like `Ross's` has too many esses in it. I wonder what the COHA has to offer for names that already end in `ss`?

Comment: How can I get data on Gauss' vs Gauss's?

Comment: @timur These days easiest with Google: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Gauss+',Gauss's&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=10

Comment: How did this post ever garner a down vote? It's one sugar plum away from being a complete Christmas dinner, for Pete's sake.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it does not address the underlying law: that the way one writes possessives in English depends solely on pronunciation. I suppose I should write up a longer answer about this sometime, as it also involves suppressing duplicate /əz/ suffixes and completely explains things like *one series’ protagonist, Achilles’ heel, states’ rights, this class’s superclass, this process’s memory, those processes’ memory, Ross’s idea, James’s father*. There is only one rule, and it is not just a rule but a law, because it is completely predictive and has no exceptions.

Comment: @RBerteig It turns out that there is no valid English possessive pronounced /səz/ that ends in a double-s plus a bare apostrophe; that must always be written *ss’s* instead. Even the somewhat archaic construct *for righteousness’ sake* does not violate this because the middle word is pronounced /ˈraɪtʃəsnəs/, and so does not end in /səz/ at all. There is just one simple  overriding law that applies to all these cases, and it has no exceptions.

Comment: @tchrist, interesting. I'll have to see if I can break a long standing habit...

Comment: @AndrewStacey: there is a British National Corpus, but it's far less extensive than COHA.

Comment: I have always objected to anyone who tried to say "Francis'" rather than "Francis's" and that's how I say it :-)

Comment: As a statistician - I'm impressed. Hence +1. As a human being I'm afraid and worried. As beautiful as it looks, where did you get the time to do that, mate?! :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten looking at the date, it looks like it was during my two-week notice period after quitting my previous job and before starting my new one.

Comment: @nohat Pfeeew. My faith in humanity's been restored. (Seriously though, I'd bounty you for that answer if I wasn't short on reputation - i.e. stingy, hihi).

Comment: @nohat Does that mean possessives of words are becoming more normalized to use **'s** instead of just the apostrophe without the s **'**?

Answer (score 13):

I can’t speak to when, but I can say that Strunk and White’s *Elements of Style* specifically says to use the *James’s* form.

Since that is taken as gospel by  — who knows, hundreds, thousands, millions? — of writers, I’m sure it has an effect on modern trends.

Comment: *The Elements of Style* (Strunk and White) puts this rule first precisely because it's the most controversial one — the goal of the book is to get you writing the way Strunk liked things. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I suspect their injunction against the passive voice would be more controversial if more people actually understood the claim being made.

Answer (score 10):

When I was taught grammar in school in the 90s and early 2000s in the northeastern United States, I was taught James's, to differentiate it from the plural possessive. (That's James's book; that's the Bryants' car.)

Comment: Must have changed around that time, then. In the 70s and 80s, "James's" would have been incorrect. "James'" was considered correct back then. I was also taught in the northeastern US (Connecticut).

Comment: There is no merit in this argument, in my opinion. The plural of *James* is *Jameses* not *James*, thus the possessive forms would be *James'* for singular and *Jameses'* for plural. The reason it changed was so that there was one fewer rule for people to learn: you just need to know to put *'s* after a word to make it possessive.

Comment: Whether or not there's merit to the argument (I happen to think there is, both for consistency and for the written form mirroring the spoken form), my answer is an accurate, factual data-point to the question asked: not which is correct, but **when** changes in usage and teaching occurred. So I'm not sure why it was considered worthy of a down-vote.

Comment: @In the Booley House, (I didn’t downvote your answer, but) I think the problem someone might have with this answer—same as with Antony’s, below—is that it doesn’t really answer the question, but just provides a data point that someone could use, along with many other data points, to answer the question.

Comment: That's fair, nohat, and your answer is certainly better than mine. Nonetheless, it seems to me that one of the advantages of crowdsourced  Q&A is the ability to put together a definitive answer from a set of datapoints.

Comment: One of the advantages of crowd-sourced Q & A is that the community gets to determine what is the best answer. While you did attempt to answer the question, you didn't go into enough depth. My answers have been down-voted before and I thought they were good -- that's the nature of the beast. No personal attack intended.

Comment: @JDOConal Maybe they intended for *Jame* to be a name?

Answer (score 2):

My recollection from school (UK, 1980s) is that the apostrophe-only version is used for Biblical names, and the apostrophe-plus-s is used for everything else. According to this rule, you would write "Jesus' friends and Seamus's friends" because the name Jesus appears in the Bible but the name Seamus does not.

Comment: That's a cruel rule. How could I possibly know what names appear in the Bible?

Comment: Can you go back there and ask for your tuition back?  They are paid to teach you things that make you smarter, not the opposite.

Comment: This argument is plainly false in my opinion. It is just a trend in English usage that *Jesus'* was used instead of *Jesus's*. Some common Biblical names may have been slower to change because of their frequent use in more archaic examples of English, but *Jesus's* is now used quite frequently, maybe even as frequently as *Jesus'*. *James*, of course, was a Biblical name. These days, people often pronounce it 'Jesuses' rather than 'Jesus' as well.

Comment: Same as the above: whether or not the argument is false, Antony's answer is an accurate, factual data-point to the question asked: not which is correct, but **when** changes in usage and teaching occurred. So I'm not sure why it was considered worthy of a down-vote.

Comment: @In the Booley House. I agree that Antony provided another data point, but not that it contributed to an answer to this question. He only enlightened us to *his* experience, and gave no information as to when general practice changed. As I wrote in the comments to the question above, down votes are part of life at this type of site. Potential answers should at least attempt to thoroughly answer the question, as only one can be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the rules (if they can be called rules) change over time. Therefore, you will be able to see the popular Christmas carol lyric '"Sire he lives a good league hence,/By St Agnes' fountain"'. The metre does not allow for "Agnes's" in order to scan.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way, I recall a tip (likely designed to simplify matters rather than clarify them) that stated that single consonant names ending in S such as James would be adjusted to James's to indicated the possessive, whereas a polysyllabic name such as Oedipus would simply get the apostrophe as in Oedipus'. Perhaps this is more of an aesthetic tip, but I like it.

Comment: So if he had a cat, it would be Oedipus's pussycat?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the justification:

For all SINGULAR nouns (other than some Bible names), add the apostrophe S, regardless of the ending letter.

For PLURAL nouns that end in S, add only the aposrophe.

Really, it's quite simple.

Comment: That's not justification, that's an assertion.  Moreover, it's not an answer to my question as the question was about changes in grammar, not about what was the "correct" behaviour.

Comment: Your heart is in the right place, but technically what you have written is untrue: the singular nouns *series* and *species* take a simple apostrophe, as of course do Socrates and Achilles, which are certainly not ‘Biblical’ names. There is a greater law at work here that you are missing.