# How do I pronounce "s's" and "s'"?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)
> [Pronouncing possessive words that already end in s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/pronouncing-possessive-words-that-already-end-in-s)

How do I pronounce possessives that end with the awkward "s's" and "'s"? Examples:

> I found the mistress's attitude ridiculous
>
> These are the eggs' shells.
>
> Which coat is Amos'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s) (the accepted answer addresses pronunciation, too) and [Pronouncing possessive words that already end in s](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/pronouncing-possessive-words-that-already-end-in-s)

Comment: @Bogdan Lataianu The answer to that question answers this question too; that is why this question is duplicate of that other question.

Answer (score 0):

You pronounce the extra syllable when it's warranted:

> ... the mistress[es]
>
> ... Amos[es]

but with this one you don't:

> ... the eggs shells [or just eggshells]

Comment: Yeah, it's like the pronounciation of _synapses_.

Comment: I think there is a difference (an audible *s*) between *eggs' shells" and *eggshells*

Comment: I think there's a semantic difference too. You wouldn't often refer to *eggs' shells*, obviously. But if you wanted to, at least your audience would know what you *said*, if not what you *meant*.

Comment: ..unless you are Gollum

Answer (score 0):

Always pronounce the "possessive 's" *unless* that would be a real tongue-twister.

So if a man with two mistresses wanted to speak of things he'd given to both of them, I'd advise him to drop the **'s**, rather than try to pronounce **mistresses's** with a straight face!

Okay, some people might then think he only had *one* mistress. But that might even be an advantage - if one of the mistressess overheard him talking about the gift[s], for example.

Comment: @Bogdan Lataianu: Ok, so why not give an example of a case where *you* think a reasonable and careful speaker would seriously attempt to either write or enunciate three consecutive **s**'s in order to include the possessive. Admittedly my particular case was light-hearted, but that was partly to show how ridiculous things get if people slavishly stick to 'rules' in inappropriate circumstances.

Comment: @Bogdan Lataianu: Thank *you* for the reappraisal, and for what looks like an Answer worth posting. May you be an asset to EL&U, as it to you. (read with sufficient aplomb and gravitas, I assure you that's good English !-)

Comment: @Bogdan Lataianu: Thanks anyway, but this question is now closed and merged. I don't think you could change a vote even if I edit the answer, and I don't think votes on closed Q's count for 'reputation' anyway. But I'm not bothered about points - I don't know how to exercise the privileges I've already got!

Answer (score 0):

Individual words broken up by • for emphasis that each word should be spoken separately. •• indicates an intake of breath may be appropriate after saying this, as a way to force yourself to say it correctly.

> I found the mistress's attitude ridiculous

I • found • the • mistresses •• attitude • ridiculous.

I presume that there are more than one mistress in reference here, which is also an oddity. I would consider this at best an exercise, and not a regular occurrence. More of a literary device for reading, than for pronunciation.

> These are the eggs' shells.

These • are • the • eggs •• shells.

It's important to remember which is which, the shells need to be differentiated from the eggs, so put that extra (yet brief) pause in there.

> Which coat is Amos'?

Which • coat • is • Amos? [pronounce the same as if it didn't have the apostrophe]

But note that this is not common usage, so I don't foresee this really coming up often. Mostly only as an exercise.

If it would be beneficial for me to put an IPA pronunciation under each word, say so and I shall do so.