# Should I answer the phone with “Mr. Beltz’s office” or “Mr. Beltz’ office”?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe

How would you pronounce the following when answering a phone for a boss whose last name is *Beltz*? Some people are saying *Mr. Beltz**’s** office*, pronouncing the extra *s*, and someone else thinks you should just say *Mr. Beltz office*.

Which one is it?

Comment: Duplicates [How do I pronounce "s's" and "s'"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22978), which is marked as a duplicate of  [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1073) and  [What is the pronunciation of the possessive words that already end in s?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5913) etc, eg  [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/79081),

Comment: @jwpat7 Yeah, but this one ends in *‑z*, not in *‑s*. :) [*ducks*]

Answer (score 3):

It’s certainly Mr Beltz’s office.  Otherwise it sounds like it belongs to one Mr Belt.  See [this answer to *Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe/79083#79083) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I thought was correct, but I just couldn't convince my colleague of it!