# How do you pronounce the possessive form of Las Vegas?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe

How do you pronounce the possessive form of Las Vegas?  Example: *Las Vegas' best radio station*

Is it correct to put only an apostrophe after the 's' when writing the possessive form of this noun?

Comment: This is a common question on here. [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22978/how-do-i-pronounce-ss-and-s) will give you a start down this particular rabbit hole. Or you can search for **s'**. Not specific to Vegas but the same rules apply for other proper nouns ending in s.

Comment: I think the most relevant previous post on this site is probably [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081) (Even though "las vegas" is plural in Spanish, I doubt that the place name "Las Vegas" can be considered to be plural in English.)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean vegan? Can't find vegas in an English dictionary.

Comment: @David: "Vegas", with a capital V, refers to the [City of Las Vegas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas) (as well as some surrounding areas, in some contexts)

Comment: @sumelic — Really! Sounds Spanish to me. Perhaps the poster should consult the city fathers.

Comment: Generally like "Las Vegases", only you mumble the last syllable.