# What’s the pronunciation of “ s’ ”?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the pronunciation of the possessive words that already end in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the-possessive-words-that-already-end-in-s)

> “The Weasley **twins’** friend, Lee Jordan, was doing the commentary for
>   the match.”

Do native English speakers pronounce *twins* and *twins’* the same way?
Or do they get said as /twɪnziz/ or /twɪnzəz/, and is this just an informal pronunciation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe is not a letter.  It is not pronounced.  It is always silent.  It cannot change a word’s pronunciation by its presence or absence.

Therefore *the twins I know* and *the twins’ mother* will pronounce the *“twins”* part of it in there exactly the same way.

The idea of *twins’* having some sort of a /ˈtwɪnzəz/ pronunciation is not just that it is informal; it is not.  It is wrong.

The word that would be pronounced that way would have to be something like *twinses*, which does not to my knowledge exist.  But if it did, then adding an apostrophe to make it possessive via *twinses’* would still leave it pronounced the same way.  Apostrophes do not change a word’s pronunciation.

Comment: The apostrophe can, however, be used to mark a difference in pronunciation: do's as opposed to DOS; I'll as opposed to ill; can't as opposed to cant. It can also signal the pronunciation of a letter one might consider to be elided: ex's.

Comment: In American English _can't_ is identical to _cant_. And the pronunciation marker use of l'apostrophe is vanishingly small.

Comment: -1 just for "Apostrophes do not change a word’s pronunciation." Not commenting on "not just that it is informal; it is not. It is wrong" as yet.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).