# What’s the pronunciation of “ s’ ”_(2)?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the pronunciation of the possessive words that already end in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the-possessive-words-that-already-end-in-s)
>   [What’s the pronunciation of “ s’ ”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97154/whats-the-pronunciation-of-s)

> Mr **Torres** will be returning to the Amazon rainforest in January next
>   year to investigate further as this masterful spider is yet to be
>   recognised as a new species.
>
> Mr **Torres'** discovery will be registered, verified and his findings
>   published if this spider proves to be biologically different from the
>   known species of Cyclosa.

[[source][1]: Report (1.1 MB) ; (1) 1:00, (2) 1:10](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/wordsinthenews/2012/12/121224_clever_spider.shtml)

This is the case against [tchrist’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97154/whats-the-pronunciation-of-s). Because the BBC’s presenter clearly differentiates the two pronunciations, Mr Torres and Mr Torres’. So I need to wait a new answer. Is the BBC’s pronunciation right or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the BBC pronunciation was correct, while the transcript should probably have been *Torres's*.

The [Singular nouns ending with an “s” or “z” sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Singular_nouns_ending_with_an_.E2.80.9Cs.E2.80.9D_or_.E2.80.9Cz.E2.80.9D_sound) section on the Wikipedia suggests that the omission of the possessive **s** from the spelling is conformant to the pronunciation, not the other way.

The possessive of "Torres" exists in both forms "Torres'", as well as "Torres's" in usage.

cf. [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/chelsea/9796518/Fernando-Torress-form-down-to-stomach-bug-not-lack-of-desire-insists-Chelsea-manager-Rafa-Benitez.html) :

> Fernando Torres's form down to stomach bug, not lack of desire, insists Chelsea manager Rafa Benitez  …
>   Benítez accepted that Torres’s £50 million price tag had raised expectations for him at Chelsea …