# How to pronounce the 's at the end of names that end with s

Tags: pronunciation

For example:
Lucas's dog was joyful.

do I pronounce the first word the exact same as if I just said Lucas, or do I say lucas-es?

Comment: See tchrist at [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe/79083#79083). Also related: [What is the pronunciation of the possessive words that already end in s?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the-possessive-words-that-already-end-in-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it with three syllables, so the second option applies.