# How to pronounce "Jobs's..."?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Should "Jobs's" be pronounced "Jobs" or "Jobsis"?

Thanks!

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the-possessive-words-that-already-end-in-s

Comment: Oh. And that one.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! So am I right - "Steve Jobs's" and "Steve Jobs'" are both acceptable? (yeah my question shifted from pronunciation to spelling^^)