# "Dawkins'" or "Dawkins's"

Tags: british-english, orthography, possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)

I learned from school to use *Dawkins'*, for example

> That is Mr. Dawkins' house.

But I see many people write *Dawkins's* instead. Is it something related to American English as opposed to British conventions?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate of several questions on this site already...

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, it does seem familiar. How would one search for this sort of thing?

Comment: Duplicates: [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s), [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending). (Found through the "Related" bar on the right.)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both forms are valid, depending on the style guide you follow.  It does not appear to be a regional thing.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Singular_nouns_ending_with_an_.E2.80.9Cs.E2.80.9D_or_.E2.80.9Cz.E2.80.9D_sound) has an overview.