# Apostrophe for words ending with the letter S

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)
>   [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)

I always had this difficulty understanding how to depict possessive nature for words ending with s.

For example: Is it correct to say, "James's heart is made of gold"? Or is there any other way to use apostrophes with words ending with S?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is up to the writer's style, there are two options:

1) James's heart is made of gold.
2) James' heart is made of gold.

@jsegal the link you posted actually confirms this:

> NOTE: Although names ending in s or an
>   s sound are not required to have the
>   second s added in possessive form, it
>   is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "James's heart is made of gold" is correct.  Though a lot of people do indeed get this wrong and confuse it with the plural possessive (which also ends in s), and would write "James'".

(See for example: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp)