# Name, Conditions, and Pluralization of "Conscience' sake"

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe, archaicisms

In some versions of the Bible, 1 Cor. 10:25 contains the phrase [*conscience' sake*](http://bible.cc/1_corinthians/10-25.htm) with no *s* following the possessive apostrophe of *conscience*, which does not end with *s*, as in:

> New American Standard Bible (©1995)
>
> Eat anything that is sold in the meat market without asking questions for conscience' sake;

I have three questions:

- Does this unique event have a name?
- When (or with what other words) does it happen? Is it because **both** *conscience* ends and *sake* begins with an *s* sound?
- Is there a distinct pluralized form, i.e. a phrase meaning only "for the sake of several/many consciences"? (A Google search suggested *conscience's' sake*.)

Comment: I reckon *conscience* is uncountable here and should be singular. But if it is pluralised, it's entirely regular and would be *consciences'*, with s-apostrophe.

Comment: Simple mechanical morphology for the possessive in the case of words ending in an 'ess' sound is adding only an apostrophe, no 's' after: *Sisters'* etc. Apparently, it was construed that the word *conscience* ending in the 'ess' sound needs no additional 's' after the apostrophe. Today we write it as *conscience's*, though, as other similar words ending in the 'ess' sound but not with the letter 's'. ...

Comment: The original idea might have been that *Sisters'* would be pronounced as ˈsɪstə(r)s and *Sisters's* as ˈsɪstə(r)s-es/ ˈsɪstə(r)s-is -- today we seldom pronounce the schwa in these instances. The intention of dropping the 's' in the present case could be to avoid a pronunciation of ˈkɑːnʃəns-e(i)s and force ˈkɑːnʃəns for *conscience'*.

Comment: *conscience's' sake* seems incorrect to me. For the plural case, it would be *consciences' sake*. Your citation refers to the singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mention the phenomenon — or old habit, perhaps — of saying *for conscience’ sake* in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083).  You’ll also see the expression *for righteousness’ sake* in older religious works.  A more common one is *for goodness’ sake*.

There’s no extra syllable in any of these, as the orthography indicates.
In all these, the formulaic **for *X*’ sake** (where *X* ends in phonetic /s/), no extra syllable is pronounced to indicate the possessive. It’s just like how a plural already ending in *-s* takes no extra syllable to create the possessive.

> this farmer’s field 
>   these farmers’ fields

People also used to end their prayers by saying *in Jesus’ name, Amen* without an extra syllable, too, but for the most part, they no longer do so.  Most (but not all) now say *in Jesus’s name, Amen* instead.

In answer to your question about a plural, *conscience* is generally construed to be a non-count noun, in which case it takes no plural inflection.  If one did, however, its plural would have to be *consciences*, and the possessive of that is the same as the possessive of any other plural already ending in *-s*: just add an apostrophe without adding an extra syllable, so *in their own consciences’ domains*.

Comment: Great post! Do you know of a term for "possessive with no *s* near the end"? Also, this may merit a new question but: Can **X noun** replace **X' noun**? In particular, can the less unusual-looking *cactus spines* replace both/either *cactus' spines* (by that I mean one cactus plant) or *cacti's spines*? Or *matrix determinant* replace *matrix' determinant*?