# When a name finishes in "s" can you say Jaume Casals's biography?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Is this sentence correct?

Here you can find Jaume Casals's biography.

I think the final " 's " is unnecessary, but I am not 100% sure. Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: and here [singular names ending in "s"...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe)

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question is answered comprehensively elsewhere as mentioned by @Mari-LouA, but can I just add that can you can often get out of situations like this by rewriting. For example:

> Here you can find a biography of Jaume Casals.