# Apostrophe on Proper Nouns that end in -s. “Louis's” vs “Louis’ '’?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, style-manuals

Though I see that many have asked the question of whether acronyms that ends with a "s" should be **s'** or **s's**, I have puzzled over whether nouns that ends in “s” should end in s's or s'.

Many sources online and in SAT books disagree with each other and I am confused because of all the disagreements.

If given the example:

> Louis’s scarf
>   Louis’ scarf

One book stated that it was Louis's while another said that it should be Louis'.

I specifically looked for the answer what College Board's SAT would agree with and I would also like to know warrants to the answer as well.

Comment: related: [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in “‑s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s) and [Why is it “Paris’s cafés” but “Massachusetts’ capital”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122082/why-is-it-paris-s-caf%C3%A9s-but-massachusetts-capital)

Comment: Also related: [When did it become correct to add an “s” to a singular possessive already ending in “‑s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)