# Pronunciation of the apostrophe

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Is there a rule regarding the pronunciation (or lack of) of the apostrophe?
I have seen this on tv:

> "Enchantress' wrath" pronounced as "Echantresses wrath"
>
> "Gus' schedule" pronounced as "Guses schedule"

According to that the following examples should be pronounced the same:

> Jones's car as "Joneses car"
>
> Jones' car as "Joneses car"

Just to make it clear, this is not a question regarding the use of the apostrophe, it's one regarding the apostrophe's pronunciation.

Comment: You should pronounce possessives the way they are supposed to be pronounced, no matter how they are spelled. So you should never pronounce "Gus' schedule" as *Gus schedule* but always *Gusses schedule*.

Comment: It seems like you're asking how the possessive clitic `'s` is pronounced, and how that pronunciation corresponds to the two possible spellings `'s` and `'`.  I don't think you're asking how the apostrophe is pronounced in general--which is good, because like most letters, it doesn't consistently correspond to any particular pronunciation.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Yes, _Jones'_ and _Jones's_ are both pronounced as _joneses_. The possessive is the possessive, it is pronounced the same way irrespective of how you spell it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the apostrophe's pronunciation". There is no such thing as a letter's pronunciation, for that matter. It's not the written language that's pronounced, it's the spoken language that's written down. So this question really makes no sense. If you say "Joneses" in your dialect or idiolect, then that's what you say, and no amount of spelling will change that. Spoken language is primary.

Comment: @terdon: Not according to [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv57.shtml): However, if the singular noun ends in 's' . . . you can either just add an apostrophe (') or apostrophe 's' ('s):
'All of Dickens' novels have now been adapted for television.'
'All of Dickens's novels have now been adapted for television.'
**Note that these spellings are pronounced differently.** If you simply add an apostrophe, the pronunciation does not change, but if you add apostrophe 's' ('s), the possessive is pronounced /iz/.

Comment: I don’t mean to harsh, but I’m sorry to report that most of this TV stuff you’ve found and mentioned is simply nonsense by people who do not know how to spell in English. **The apostrophe is never pronounced.**  Somehow a generation or two of people got confused about possessives and started spelling them wrong: that is, in a way that forgets speech. They forgotten that — as @RegDwigнt wrote — ***speech is always primary***.  See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083) for more about this tragedy.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, but I would even more stress the other way around: that ***you should always spell possessives the way they are supposed to be pronounced***. That is the critical bit, and somewhere it got lost in our post-modern post-literate post-society’s posts.

Comment: What @Edwin said. In my experience, very few speakers bother to enunciate a second "possessive" ***s*** when talking about, say, *Dickens' novels*. And even if they *did* happen to be reading out loud from a text, I don't think they'd normally vary their pronunciation depending on whether the written form had that extra ***s*** or not.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I rather liked 'there have been [at least] **three** rules promulgated for spelling possessives in the history of English. (1) only add an apostrophe when the word ends with in an 's' (2) always add 's (3) spell them the way they're pronounced.' I'd add (4) (the reference above) choose either spelling and pronounce accordingly (I haven't seen the hierarchy of rule-makers tchrist implies) and pronunciation rule (x) Pronounce either spelling the way you prefer.

Comment: Apostrophe's are completely silent, whether theyre us'ed for contractions, plural's, or genitives. So you needn't pronounce them at all. In any event, English' spelling is full of things you dont pronounce, so theres no real problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, with regard to spelling: "Today it is no longer considered incorrect to [use either form](http://www.edufind.com/english/punctuation/apostrophe.php) (Jones's or Jones') ".

Secondly, ncsu ties together [pronunciation and spelling](http://www.ncsu.edu/ncsu/grammar/Apostro3.html) to a limited degree:

> Spelling conventions are in some sense an attempt to replicate
> pronunciation. When style manuals make pronouncements on spelling,
> they imply that the presence of an extra "s" means that most educated
> speakers customarily pronounce that sound. The reason that this system
> cannot simply be reversed to produce pronunciation rules is that style
> manuals are directed at written language, and they are thus also
> interested in visual consistency and eliminating visual distractions.

This is in answer to the question:

> In American English, how are words that end in "s's" pronounced? For
> example, if Jones is pronounced as "Jonz," how is Jones's pronounced?
> And if the above were written to end with the apostrophe (Jones'), is
> the final "s" silent? Listening to the radio, I notice that many
> announcers seem to treat the final "s" as silent; but I feel the final
> "s" should be pronounced as a separate syllable, even in cases where
> the word is written to end with the apostrophe only.

[This article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv57.shtml) says that you can choose between the addition of the bare apostrophe or the apostrophe s in these cases, but that this then dictates how the resultant should be pronounced. Yet another rule dropped from on high.

This article from [Grammar and Style in British English](http://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-the-apostrophe.html) implies that there is a rigorous connection between pronunciation and written form; it recommends that you should decide whether one pronunciation sounds more reasonable, and choose the spelling to correspond as closely as possible. For Jones' / Jones's and Wales' / Wales's, it implies there is no obviously better choice:

> Where possessive nouns ending in s make a harsh ziz sound, the option
> is available of using an apostrophe without an additional s. Thus –
>
> Jones’s house is the one at the end of the street
>
> may instead be written
>
> Jones’ house is the one at the end of the street.
>
> Similarly –
>
> Gareth Edwards was one of Wales’s (or Wales’) finest rugby players.
>
> But the traditional practice is to retain the additional s
> (Jones's house) unless the resulting pronunciation would be
> particularly ungainly –
>
> Moses’ tablets  /    Cervantes’ Don Quixote  /     Jesus’ disciples

Ultimately, one has to decide whether one is sufficiently pro-'Joneses' to read out *Jones'* as 'Joneses', etc. In a sense, 'only read the form *Jones's* as 'Joneses' is prescriptivist. One faces a very similar problem when quoting a passage with alternative spellings one doesn't use, when quoting passages using different spellings, when reading out 'Wagner conducted the Wagner piece' ...