# Should an apostrophe be used with a z at the end of a word?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I know that if a word ends with an **s** then it should be made plural or possessive by use of an apostrophe with no extra s (e.g. "Thomas Harris' book was a riveting read." as opposed to "Gary Barlow's voice is so distracting.")

What about if the word ends with a **z**. For example, would it be **Gomez'** album or **Gomez's** album?

Comment: I don't know where you got that rule from. I would be very happy to write Harris's (and pronounce that in 3 syllables). Which means I would also write Gomez's.

Comment: I believe it is more with plural words, like a boys' school, but I am sure I was taught to just use the apostrophe, maybe I am wrong then...

Comment: "**Gomez's** album" it is, pronunciation does not matter here. What if "**Gomez'** album" is interpreted as "**Gomez'z** album" following the same logic as the possessive **'s** ? :)

Comment: That's a good point. I will use Gomez's album then. Thank you :)

Comment: “… if a word ends with an **s** then it should be made ***plural*** … by use of an apostrophe with no extra **s** ….” This is wrong. For most cases, you add **es** (e.g., atlases, classes, guesses). If the singular noun ends with **is**, you sometimes change **is** to **es** (axis -> axes, crisis -> crises, parenthesis -> parentheses) or sometimes *add* **es** (iris -> irises, trellis -> trellises). If the word is “already plural” (e.g., means, headquarters) the plural may be the same (“All my pants are blue”). There may be other rules, but you never form a plural by adding an apostrophe.

Comment: Related: [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various views regarding proper nouns ending in s.

**The Times Style and Usage Guide (2011):**

> apostrophes with proper names/nouns ending in s that are singular, [...] where the final 's' is soft, use the 's' apostrophe, eg, Rabelais' writings, Delors' presidency

**The Guardian Style Guide (2007):**

> The possessive in words and names ending in S normally takes an
>   apostrophe followed by a second S (Jones's, James's), but be guided by
>   pronunciation and use the plural apostrophe where it helps:
>   Mephistopheles', Waters', Hedges' rather than Mephistopheles's,
>   Waters's, Hedges's.

In both guides pronunciation has an impact on the use of s after the apostrophe. These guides, however, only consider names ending in s. I suspect, given the guiding principles stated in the guides, that these rules could be extended to names ending in z when the z is pronounced s.

In any case, I would write Gomez's as this is not difficult to pronounce.