# What is the possessive form of Bliss as a proper noun?

Tags: nouns, possessives

My daughter is named Bliss. We want to know how to label things like "Bliss's Toy Box" or would it be "Blisses Toy Box" or "Bliss' Toy Box" as you can tell I'm quite confused... Help please :)

Comment: Please look at this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe

Comment: It's *Bliss's*.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations!

And when you come to stay in England you can spell it Bliss's and pronounce it Blissiz.

However if you ever need to discuss *The Times* 's Front Page, use *italics*, to avoid this "The Times'" or this "The Times"'s.

And in Poetry and the Bible use the old-fashioned style: Venus' bath, Achilles' thews, Jesus' ministry. (No extra syllable!)

But in everyday use it should be Charles's Wain, Jones's children, Pythagoras's theorem. Each is pronounced with final -*zez* or -*ses* as an extra syllable.

So says *Modern Englishm Usage* by H.W.Fowler whose examples I have used and whose words I have condensed,

Comment: You pronounce it **BlissIZ**, not **BlissES**.

Comment: That's not “the American” way. That’s the way that the Chicago Manual of Style says not to use.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks.  I'm very pleased to hear that. and will edit the ( ) out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers; now I'm able to edit IZ  -thanks.

Comment: @tchrist: As I'm sure I've mentioned elsewhere, we nearly always write [St James's Park](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=St+James+Park%2CSt+James%27+Park%2CSt+James%27s+Park&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSt%20James%20Park%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSt%20James%20%27%20Park%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSt%20James%20%27s%20Park%3B%2Cc0). And most of the times we *don't* include the **s**, we at least write the apostrophe, But in my experience people often don't *say* the **-IZ** part even though they clearly know it "exists" orthographically.