# Using the Chicago Manual of Style, do colons go inside or outside quotes?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, colons, style-manuals

I have the following sentence:

> The program identifies particular “targets” and “identifiers:” the “targets” are people who are suspected of committing a crime.

Does the colon go inside the quotes or outside of them?

Comment: You either have to purchase it or find it at a library. Why ask that here??

Comment: @Lambie because I have seen many other useful punctuation questions here. I did not know that style manuals could be proprietary. I thought the point was that everyone should be able to know them and use them.

Comment: If it were entirely free, it would be online. The Chicago Manual of Style is a book, not a style guide (as you find in companies).  Any named reference book has a copyright.

Comment: If you are quoting single words in a text, the quotation marks (aka inverted commas) must go around the word. You would never ever but them after a colon. This isn't dialogue or quoting a person. And I reckon that rule is the same in most places where English is the official language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While my edition (14th) of CMOS is getting long in the tooth, I don’t believe the guidance has changed:

> **5.104** The colon should be placed outside quotation marks or parentheses. When matter ending with a colon is quoted, that colon is dropped:
>
> > Kego had three objections to “Filmore’s Summer”: it was contrived; the characters were flat; the dialogue was unrealistic.

@Sven Yargs notes in a comment that the guidance remains in place in the 16th (2010) edition:

> **6.10 *Other punctuation in relation to closing quotation marks*** Colons and semicolons—unlike periods and commas—follow closing quotation marks; ..."

Comment: The advice you cite from the 14th edition remains in force in the 16th edition (2010): "**6.10 _Other punctuation in relation to closing quotation marks_** Colons and semicolons—unlike periods and commas—follow closing quotation marks; ..."

Comment: This is not the kind of thing they would change....

Comment: In general, Chicago upholds the doctrine of _stare decisis_ at least as vigorously as the U.S. Supreme Court does, but occasionally it reverses itself—even (in one recent instance) on a [matter of punctuation style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe/422888#422888).

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer your question directly, reading your sentence, I would think that the quotation marks could be eliminated. There is no need for scare quotes in that sentence, since there is nothing unusual or inaccurate about your usage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes#Criticism

Comment: The example does not use scare quotes; rather, this is a straightforward example of using quotes to define a term, much like a Stack Exchange "answer" is different from just any Stack Exchange answer.