# Question about capitalization after a colon, as well as a few others going on in an otherwise-unimportant sentence I wrote

Tags: commas, capitalization, semicolons, quotation-marks, colons

Not exactly a life-or-death situation here, it's just a YouTube comment I'm in the process of typing in a discussion on movies, the MCU, and the MCU's version of Spider-Man. Sometimes, I write a sentence and immediately question the syntax, but this time I have four distinct questions about one silly sentence, and I figure I may as well ask so I'll have that information in the future.

> It's the same reason I don't really care for any of the other
> "spiders":  A huge reason for Spidey's success was that he was unique,
> and he was a loner; there was no one else like him in comics.

1. The primary question that has me going as far as to ask for clarification: Is this the proper usage of capitalization after a colon?  But then, I immediately have other questions.
2. Does the colon belong in or out of the quotation mark?  If it matters, this is a case of quotes being used to denote what people are unofficially calling other characters with the same power set, not a direct quote from someone.
3. Is double-spacing after a colon still correct?  I know that it's no longer encouraged to double-space after every sentence as I was taught back in typing class (though I still do it out of habit and preference), and I could swear we were taught the same for colons, but I don't know if it's the current, proper syntax.
4. Should there be a comma after "unique"? <-- (And does that question mark belong in or out of the quotation marks?)
5. Is the usage of a semicolon toward the end of the sentence correct?  I think I've started to overuse semicolons the way my English professor once told me I overuse parenthetical phrases, but is it grammatically correct?  I'm especially concerned considering everything else going on in the sentence, but it **is** important to me (for...whatever reason) to keep closely-related thoughts connected in this sort of way.  But is too much?

Comment: Double-spacing fell by the wayside with the advent of word processors and computers. Programs will adjust the spacing properly if you type just one space.

Comment: With regard to your first question above, see [Should the first word after a colon be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/should-the-first-word-after-a-colon-be-capitalized)

Comment: There should not be a capital letter after a colon unless the colon introduces a list. The quotation marks round a single word count as part of that word and do not affect other punctuation.

Comment: Welcome! This is a well-communicated question, but note that Stack Exchange works best when individual questions are posted and get focused answers. In this case we could consider questions 1-3 to count as "one question" about colon usage, but it might be nice to pull the comma and semicolon questions out into their own posts. ...

Comment: ... Also, note that general proofreading requests are not [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is not one—you very clearly identify your points of concern—but just saying that a "here's one post to generally fix everything with this passage" approach isn't really applicable.

Comment: With regard to your second question, see "Using the Chicago Manual of Style, do colons go inside or outside quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439067/using-the-chicago-manual-of-style-do-colons-go-inside-or-outside-quotes/439088#439088) (I will add that I haven't seen any style that recommends adding a colon inside a close quotation mark unless it is there in the original text being quoted.)

Comment: [Re double-spacing](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-many-spaces-after-a-colon): "Just as with the period, it used to be common to put two spaces after a colon, but now most style guides that address the matter (e.g., The Chicago Manual of Style) recommend using only one space after a colon."

Comment: Re semicolons: incorrect usage and overuse are two different concerns. And stylistic writing advice is off-topic here, but your usage is valid, and IMO is appropriate. Hemingway might enjoy breaking the sentence there, but that casts doubt on the preceding use of the colon. (Well, I guess he'd break there too.)

Comment: And if we *did* give subjective, stylistic advice... I'd say this is in no way an over-complicated or over-structured sentence, and the colon and semicolon are doing exactly what they were made for, and I would have written the exact same sentence (though *maybe* without the comma). I'd love to hear somebody tackle the question mark, but last I heard, you can get both answers on that one.

Comment: I don't have access to the CMOS, but the snippets shown by [a search](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.epl?q=question%2520mark&site=cmosfaq) seem to show that section 6.70 puts the question mark outside: "... mark should be placed inside quotation marks, parentheses, or brackets only when it is part of..." ... which surely concludes, "the quoted material."