# Sirius the Dog Star shines brightly

Tags: apostrophe

If I wanted to refer to the magnitude (brightness) of Sirius, would "Sirius's magnitude" be a (the?) correct form for placing the ending 's' and apostrophe? I always get confused about possessive forms of words already ending in an 's.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe). The overarching rule accepted on ELU has been "add 's if and only if another syllable is pronounced'. As for actual preferred usage, that can be checked using Google searches, ngrams etc.

Comment: If you want to use a posessive  's' then "Sirius's" would be correct. It's a singular proper noun ending in 's' just like Louis, Janis, Jones and so on. The only argument would be about the pronunciation, some people (like me) would prefer both 's's to be pronounced, others would not.

Answer (score 0):

Usage has always been "*the magnitude of Sirius*". "*Sirius's magnitude*" is not found, nor is "Sirius' magnitude'. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sirius%27s+magnitude%2Cthe+magnitude+of+Sirius&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20magnitude%20of%20Sirius%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20magnitude%20of%20Sirius%3B%2Cc0))

[image]