# Jones's or Jones'?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, proper-nouns, saxon-genitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)
>   [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)

I've always heard that when talking about stuff belonging to either a Jones or many Jones, you'd write *Jones'* (pronounced "Joneses"). But recently I've stumbled upon a book which consistently uses *Jones's* when talking of a single Jones.

What's the correct way of using possesives?

Answer (score 1):

Both are used.  This is an area of controversy where no 'correct' way has been established.  Some sources would say that Oliver Twist is *Dickens'* character while other sources (like Strunk & White) would say that he is *Dickens's* character.  See [this page](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/preposterous-apostrophes-i-possessives/) for a brief exploration of some of the rules different sources use in different situations.

It's probably safest to stick with the *'s* ending unless it would make the pronunciation awkward or violate historical usage.  For instance, you would want to write *Achilles' heel*, not *Achilles's heel*.

Comment: No! It's "my Achilles heel", but "Achilles's heel was his secret weakness", just as it's "his Martin Luther King determination", but "Martin Luther King's determination was phenomenal".

Answer (score 0):

The rule I was taught when I was young was that one would use the *s'* when there is more than one syllable in the name, and *s's* when there is only one. The *s* following the apostrophe is pronounced whenever it occurs in writing.

Comment: Pronunciation is indeed the key: Dialects differ even though the "grammar" of this issue strongly favors the inclusion (and pronunciation) of the possessive s on any singular noun, whether it ends in s (or z) or not. So: "Jones's" and "Horowitz's" but "the Joneses' house" and "the Horowitzes' house" (because they already have the fricative plural ending--which is not the case for "children's" or "mice's", where the s possessive is added to a plural noun). (Some dialects even leave off the plural suffix on nouns that end in s, so that "the Horowitzes' house" becomes "the Horowitz' house".)