# Is it OK to have an apostrophe at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

Earlier I wrote a sentence that happened to end with a plural possessive. Is this OK to have? For example, "I got the guys' costumes, but not the girls'." looks odd to me. It would be easy to reword or simply add costumes at the end, but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Punctuation cannot possibly be correct or incorrect *grammatically*. There are no apostrophes *at all* in speech. Grammar [means something else](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/26283/300) entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following progression:

> "I found my ticket, but not yours."
>
> "I found my ticket, but not John's."
>
> "I've enjoyed some Victorian novels, but not Dickens's." [pronunciation as indicated]
>
> "I found our tickets, but not the Smiths'." [pronunciation as indicated]
>
> "I saw our neighbours at the show, but not the Smiths'."

I think the perceived problem is with the ambiguity when reading out the plural possessive. Odd-sounding, and perhaps better rephrased, but I wouldn't say breaking any rule of grammar.

Comment: Hi Edwin. In your example, why wouldn't it be "Williams'?" Is this just a typo, or purposeful use of "Williams's?"

Comment: It could be either (this has been discussed [before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35654/joness-or-jones) ), but I wanted the Williams's and Smiths' versions, with the convention (accepted by some but not all) that the s's variant adds/marks an extra syllable, in that order to illustrate the progressive descent into ambiguity.

Comment: With 'William' and 'Williams' both being surnames, I've switched to 'Dickens'. The possessive (singular) is argued to be Dickens' or Dickens's, and usually to correspond logically to two or three syllables. Here, the unapostrophised abstractish noun _Dickens_ (ie his works) also works.

Comment: With your edit, the distinction is intuitively clearer. With your explanation, the distinction is crystal clear. Cheers.

Comment: @msam That's what Dickens does for you.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically there's nothing wrong with your sentence, the grammar checks out. If it still feels a little too funky for you, you could try:

*I got the costumes for the guys, but not for the girls.*

Comment: Still marginally ambiguous, but would work fine in 99% of cases.

Comment: Could be interpreted to mean that the guys wanted both costumes and girls, but were disappointed, and got only costumes.

Comment: @DaveBurton good point. I added a word to make it disambiguous ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly correct and accepted usage to end a sentence with an apostrophe, but what is technically correct may not always satisfy the ear. As for the previous answer, it's better but still slightly off. Try "I got the costumes for the guys but not *for* the girls," which eliminates the slight ambiguity. (It sounds like you're *getting the girls* rather than the costumes for them.)