# Strunk and White says "Charles's" is correct -- is this still the case?

Tags: possessives, writing-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)
>   [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)

I just bought *The Elements of Style*, an awesome little book. However, in the first section, the authors promote the use of **'s**, no matter what the last letter of a word is, to show possessiveness.

Some examples they use:

> - Charles's friend
> - Burns's poems

Are these grammatically correct?

Comment: How about writing a second S only if you pronounce a second S?

Comment: On a more general note, read [50 years of stupid grammar advice](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497) and dump the book.

Comment: Although their advice in this is fine so far as it goes, Strunk&White do a poor job of explaining the underlying phonological rule here, and how it’s ineluctably connected to the spelling. See my answer for what’s really going on.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 That’s far too harsh. Explain to people what is really going on, and why.

Comment: @Mitch: The linked answers do not answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's down to personal preference -- but the modern convention, in my opinion, is to omit the final *s*. I'd always advocate omitting the final *s* because it's simply unnecessary: the apostrophe, by itself, clearly denotes possession.  Whether or not American English adopts this is another matter...

But with British usage, it can often be quite erratic and anachronistic.  A typical example is when I get on the London underground every day (the Piccadilly line going eastwards).  One stop is called *Baron's Court* and its immediate neighbour is *Earls Court*.

You also get this with particular brands who choose to omit the apostrophe for clarity (like Twinings, and Waterstone's has announced it's dropping its apostrophe soon).  So, in modern usage, the general trend is to omit the apostrophe. Another convention I've worked a lot with ([MHRA's](http://mhra.org.uk/Publications/Books/StyleGuide/StyleGuideV2_3.pdf) -- which I only use in academic essays) chooses to use the additional *s* for singular possession, and omit it for plural possession; so, for example: *the boss’s daughter* and *the bosses’ daughters*.

To answer Henry's point, there is no debate over '*St*' and '*St.*'. Because St James' Park refers to Saint James, the use of St is a contraction.  You put a full-stop after an abbreviation (like *Prof*.), but you never put a full-stop after a contraction because the final letter of the abbreviated form is the same as the final letter of the full form (which is why you see *Mr*, *St*, *Mrs*, etc.)

Comment: "it's dropping it's apostrophe" has an error

Comment: According to the Royal Parks it is [St James's Park](http://www.royalparks.gov.uk/St-Jamess-Park.aspx) but for London Underground it is [St. James's Park](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/gettingaround/stations/1000221.aspx)

Comment: @Henry If I said I was being deliberately ironic you wouldn't believe me, would you? :P

Comment: I would certainly accept deliberate to make a point.  My comment was really aimed at later readers.

Comment: I've heard some say that you add apostrophe-s to a word with only one 's', but only apostrophe to a word with two s's. In other words, *Charles's* and *Moses'*.

Comment: Another point of how erratic it can be in the UK, different papers use different styles. The _Guardian_ tends to go with _Burns' poems_ while _The Times_ uses _Burns's poems_ (or is it the other way around?)

Comment: As another point, my spellchecker on Firefox did try to correct _Burns's poems_

Comment: The right answer is not what you say.  Your answer is wrong. The right anwer is that the spelling follows the pronunciation, and so if you say an *s* you add an *s* in spelling. The apostrophe can never stand in for an *s* sound. There are certain fossilized uses in official toponyms where you have to follow whatever the local spelling is no matter what the pronunciation, but that is a very rare exception. In all other cases, you have to spell it according to its pronunciation. See my answer for details. @MaxMackie should take careful note.

Comment: @tchrist Actually, no. There are no absolute guidelines set out in stone.  As I specified in my answer, it's really down to personal preference or an institution's stylistic guidelines; as long as you're consistent, it's fine. As to the spoken influence, I'm not really quite sure that's the case. I would pronounce St James' and St James's exactly the same. Why would the added _s_ transform the word's pronunciation?

Comment: @Jamie That’s like asking why you would pronounce the *s* in the word *Jamie’s*! Because that’s how it’s done, is why: the added *s* reflects the word’s pronunciation. I have close family and friends who go by James, and I promise you that they all say *James’s whatever* with an added /ɨz/ (or /əz) added for the possessive. An apostrophe is strictly silent; it’s never pronounced at all, let alone as /ɨz/. It serves here only to mark the written word as being in the genitive, not to change its spoken pronunciation. For that, we have the letter *s*.

Comment: @tchrist According to your theory, _James'_ is pronounced differently from _James's_ which, I argue, is wrong. The additional _s_ should not transform the pronunciation: the possessive is pronounced the same with or without the added _s_.

Comment: @Jamie I strongly disagree with all that. It’s this very sort of thing that causes all the confusion. Stick with a strict spelling rule that reflects the pronunciation, and you have a deterministic and predictable system. Thrown it out, and you lose that. It is nonsensical.

Comment: @tchrist I wrote down, on three different sheets of paper, the following: _James' boat_, _Mary's Boat_, and _James's Boat_. I asked 3 of my friends/family to read them aloud. Every single one of them pronounced _James's_ and _James'_ the same :P

Answer (score 7):

The rule is very simple, and it has no exceptions: that you add an *s* **if you say** the *s*, which is almost always.

That said, because we don’t say the extra *s* when speaking certain limited phrases like these following examples, they therefore necessarily take no added *s* in spelling:

- that species’ name
- this series’ final episode
- your Achilles’ heel
- Diogenes’ lamp
- for goodness’ sake
- for righteousness’ sake

(Explanation: If the word ends in unstressed /iːz/, it is invariant in the face of any /ɨz/ inflection, whether for plural or possessive forms. There are very few of these, very nearly all of which are proper nouns from Greek or sometimes Latin.  The other case above is the formulaic “for ***_*__** sake”, which has a fossilized omission in speech.)

Most speakers, however, *do* always say the /ɨz/ form for the possessive in all these, so they all *do* add a final *s* in writing, to show that we sake it in speech:

- that genus’s sole representative species
- Alice’s mom
- in Jesus’s name, Amen. [**Note**: Some people *don’t* actually say the added /ɨz/ for this one, in which case those people alone omit the extra *s* here.]
- the corpse’s decay
- the corpus’s curator
- the virus’s spread
- James’s dad
- the capital s’s shape
- Gabriel García Márquez’s greatest work
- the process’s run state
- the kiss’s wetness
- the lass’s appearance
- my boss’s idea
- the Blitz’s impact
- jazz’s exotic harmonies
- the topaz’s native color
- Aunt Agnes’s new husband

It’s important to remember that the apostrophe represents no sound whatsoever, so if you say an extra sound, you have to use an extra letter.  There is no exception to this rule; it’s not as though in certain words the apostrophe suddenly stands for the /ɨz/ sound. That’s the mistake people make.  **If  you need the sound, then you need the letter, which is *s*.**

Comment: The rule for pronunciation is a little more complicated that that ... lots of people don't add an extra 's' to last names (especially multi-syllabic ones) that already sound like they're plurals, so you get *Adams'*, *Roberts'* or *Richards'*.

Comment: @PeterShor How is it more complicated? I said *if you say it, you write it.* You have given no contradiction.

Comment: I was talking about the rules you gave for pronunciation, not for spelling.

Comment: @PeterShor I didn’t intend to give rules for pronunciation, only for spelling. The key point is that the spelling reflects the pronunciation, because speech is dominant. I did mention that some people say *in Jesus’ name* instead of saying *in Jesus’s name*.

Answer (score 5):

Those examples are fine in my opinion, though preferences vary.  A classic example in England is

- [St James's Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._James%27s_Park) in London
- [St James' Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_James%27_Park) in Newcastle
- [St James Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_James_Park,_Exeter) in Exeter

And then there is the debate over *St* and *St.*.

Comment: I apologize if this sounds rude or harsh, but are rules like these up to personal preference, or are they more ingrained in English grammar rules?

Comment: They are personal preference in this particular case. If you pronounce the extra *s* then you should write it, but some English speakers pronounce it and others don't.

Comment: The possessive in English is **always** about how it's pronounced. It's grammar, and therefore is about the real (i.e, **spoken**) language. Spelling and especially punctuation is variable, but pronunciation is the true, the blushful Hippocrene.

Comment: These examples are all proper nouns which by their nature don't necessarily conform to grammatical rules. And whether there was ever more than one St James in a Newcastle park I really don't know :)

Comment: @JohnLawler I cannot agree more strongly: you are exactly right. This critical point is lost in the other answers posted here and in all the answers in the supposedly dup questions, too. It’s therefore very frustrating that this crucial point of yours gets lost.

Answer (score 2):

As an American English teacher I teach students not to use s's.

Strunk and White provide interesting and useful hints, but be careful as it's almost 100 years old and doesn't keep up with a lot of modern usage.

Comment: Then you are setting a poor example, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires a two-part answer. You want to know if it is *still* the case that “Charles’s” is grammatically correct, as prescribed by Strunk and White over fifty years ago.

1. It is the case that “Charles’s” is still grammatically correct, because writing reflects speech and most native speakers still pronounce the *s* twice.
2. That is not to say that “Charles’ ” is ungrammatical: it simply reflects a choice to pronounce the *s* once. And it was not ungrammatical fifty years ago, either. *The Elements Of Style* has never been a useful book. It is merely a popular one:

   > *The Elements of Style* does not deserve the enormous esteem in which it is held by American college graduates. Its advice ranges from limp platitudes to inconsistent nonsense. Its enormous influence has not improved American students’ grasp of English grammar; it has significantly degraded it. … Strunk had very little analytical understanding of syntax, White even less. Certainly White was a fine writer, but he was not qualified as a grammarian. (Geoffrey K. Pullum. “[50 Years of Stupid Grammar Advice](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497)”, *The Chronicle Review*, April 17, 2009. Retrieved July 12, 2013.)