# How to handle the possessive case of the name Franks

Tags: possessives, proper-nouns, surnames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)
>   [When did it become correct to add an 's' to a singular possessive already ending in 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending)

Hey guys I was wondering where to put the ' when using the possessive case of my surname, Franks. I've seen it done all the ways given below, depending on what family member wrote it, but I was wondering which one was correct?

1. Franks'
2. Franks's
3. Frankses'

Comment: If you pronounce it "Frankses", you should spell it *Franks's*. If you pronounce if "Franks", you should spell it *Franks'*.  It should not be spelled *Frankses'* unless you're talking about more than one of you.

Comment: @Peter Shor I agree and thank you I didn't come across that question in my searching. I don't suppose I can close the question myself can I?