# Possessives of a title in italics

Tags: possessives, italics

If one writes a word in italics, say the name of a movie, and wants to put apostrophe s at the end to form the possessive, is the apostrophe s italicised with the title? *Chinatown's* or *Chinatown*'s?

Answer (score 10):

No, you should not italicise the *'s*.

The reason behind that is that italicisation is part of giving importance or a style to a title, now if you italicize the *'s* it will become part of the name itself. But if you don't continue the italicisation it will mean that you have added it on purpose.

- ***Chinatown's*** means the movie name is "Chinatown's".
- ***Chinatown***'s means that you are saying something particular to the movie and the italicsation is for purpose.

Comment: I can't find a definitive source on this.  Wikipedia agrees ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe ):  "Was _She‍‍ _'​‍s success greater, or _King Solomon’s Mines‍‍ _'​‍s?"  Other non-authoritative sources I find online agree.  I'd say this is the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's better to rewrite the possessive of something inanimate (like a movie).

> Chinatown's plot... => The plot of *Chinatown*...

This becomes even more evident when the movie ends in an s.

> The Silence of the Lambs's protagonist... => The protagonist of *Silence of the Lambs*...

While this sidesteps your question, if one must choose how to italicize, italicize the title but not the apostrophe.

Please also see [When did it become correct to add an “s” to a singular possessive already ending in “‑s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending).

Comment: While I take your point, I feel compelled to remind people that there is nothing wrong with saying “This car’s paint job leaves something to be desired.”  Animacy is immaterial.

Comment: Cars shouldn't be employed in painting.

Answer (score 1):

Found a source! - per CMOS 8.170, the possessive after a title of work is NOT italic. They give this example:

*The New Yorker*’s cartoons generally have nothing to do with the surrounding text.