# “state's secrets” vs. “state secrets”

Tags: orthography, possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

Is it **state's secrets** or **state secret**?

I am always confused when I try to put " 's " to things .

I have read answers about use of the possessive apostrophe but I am not sure whether this should be:

> stat**e's** secrets
>
> or
>
> **state** secrets

I think that the state does own secrets and I think  that the first one is right, is it? And please, I need a clear explanation for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The possessive s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178548/the-possessive-s)

Comment: Either one is suitable, it depends on the context. The first says **who owns** the secrets, i.e. "the state", the second describes what ***type*** of secrets they are. You need to provide a sentence.

Comment: I don't think this question is  a duplicate of the older one. It's trickier than at first glance.

Comment: [Answers to Readers’ Questions **About State’s Secrets**](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/29/world/29askthetimes.html?pagewanted=all)

Comment: [Possession and personification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147922/possession-and-personification/147929#147929) addresses the general question.

Answer (score 1):

There is clear evidence from government websites, the New York Times, and other authoritative publications, that *state secrets* is written without an apostrophe expressing possession.

[Wkipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_secrets_privilege):

> The state secrets privilege is a common law evidentiary rule that
>   allows the government to withhold information from discovery when
>   disclosure would be inimical to national security."

[Center for Constitutional Rights](https://ccrjustice.org/home/get-involved/tools-resources/fact-sheets-and-faqs/faqs-what-are-state-secrets):

> FAQs: What Are State Secrets

[The New York Times](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/03/08/us/justice-department-cia-psychologists-interrogation-program.html?rref=collection%2Ftimestopic%2FState%20Secrets%20Privilege&action=click&contentCollection=timestopics&region=stream&module=stream_unit&version=latest&contentPlacement=1&pgtype=collection&_r=0&referer=https://www.nytimes.com/topic/subject/state-secrets-privilege):

> State Secrets Privilege Invoked to Block Testimony in C.I.A. Torture
>   Case

Also in Japan, source: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/dec/05/whistleblowers-japan-crackdown-state-secrets):

> Japan whistleblowers face crackdown under proposed state secrets law

In conclusion the evidence is clear, there is no apostrophe in *state secrets*.

Why is this? Because state is acting like an adjective here, to describe the type of secrets, the *state* doesn't actually possess the secrets.

The same concept is applied to *farmers markets*, in the following explanation from [grammar girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/apostrophes) at quick and dirty tips:

> Does ‘Farmers Market’ Have an Apostrophe?
>
> Here’s an even trickier one: farmers market. The market is used by the
>   farmers, populated by the farmers, but generally not owned by the
>   farmers. So it seems reasonable to conclude that you don't use an
>   apostrophe because the word farmers is there to identify the type of
>   market. It's acting like an adjective...

.