# Why does “today’s lesson” seem to be possessive?

Tags: orthography, possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

Why do we say the following?

> 1. I'll have an hour's wait at the airport
> 2. Today's lesson
> 3. Yesterday's programme
> 4. Two weeks' worth of groceries.

They are not possessive, or are they? Why is the possessive apostrophe used with time expressions and adverbs?

Comment: Yes, they are genitive constructions -- more specifically "attributive genitives" where, unlike in most genitives, the genitive noun is an attributive modifier within a nominal.

Comment: In _Bob's example_, the construction is a true possessive: Bill has a degree of ownership (whether he quoted or invented the example). But the same construction is also used to show associative rather than possessive relations: the car's front offside wheel (still arguably showing a measure of 'possession', though the car doesn't have ownership rights);  Bishop's Stortford; King's Cross/Kings Cross; Lloyd's vs Lloyds; an hour's wait; tomorrow's programme.

Comment: Related: [possession and personification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147922/possession-and-personification/147929#147929).

Comment: Many people here will tell you *today's lesson* is *merely* associative and if that were true, what difference would it make?

Answer (score 1):

As many have said in comments, it is a genitive construction, but not strictly *possessive*. Compare by rewording, replacing the **'s** with **for/of**:

> 1. I'll have to wait **for an hour** at the airport (or a wait **of an hour**)
> 2. The lesson **for today**
> 3. The programme **of yesterday**
> 4. Groceries **for two weeks**.