# When should apostrophe-s be used?

Tags: grammar, saxon-genitive

(Sorry for the lack of proper terms in this question)

I noticed that in this example:

```
This page's content [...]
```

The word "page" is used with an apostrophe-s. I thought `'s` should only be used when the literal translation is "[this] page **is** [...]"

Can someone please clarify this use?

Comment: See [this blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/11/much-ado-about-possessive-apostrophes/) for an explanation.

Comment: I came across an answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108150/apostrophes-and-ss) which may be useful.

Comment: Start by looking up [*'s*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%27s) in a dictionary of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [possessive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) form which is used with `'s`. Here both “page” and “content” are nouns. It means:

> Content of this page...

This form can also be used with plural nouns as in:

> The cars' trunks...

which menas:

> Trunks of the cars...

but it should not be mixed with usage of “content” as an adjective:

> The boy's content.

in which “content” means “happy” or “pleased”:

> The boy is content.