# Need confirmation of usage of apostrophes

Tags: abbreviations

i often saw sentences like

> Inside we have the Curve’s, a cleaning tool, and 2 pairs of Comply’s.

is *'s* meaning the word being possessed or abbreviation?

Comment: Some people would identify it as merely an error. If the words (before the _'s_'s) were in italics, this would be a standard pluralisation of words-used-as-words, possibly used in an unorthodox fashion here because scare-quotes + apostrophe is dire. I've found "2 pairs of Comply™ Foam Tips", which is what I'd use if I had to.

Comment: This seems like a fairly standard [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_.28.22greengrocers.E2.80.99_apostrophes.22.29). Apostrophes are used to form plurals only very rarely. Here's a relevant answer: [108153](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/108153/18696)

Comment: Why bother with plurals? A singular will do for any brand name: _Curve_ is around the corner, Swiff over there, and Comply down that aisle_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing these sentences because **nobody understands the correct use of the apostrophe any more.**

The meaning is neither possessive nor abbreviation, it's simply plural, and correct grammar would indicate that an apostrophe is not used. However the misuse of apostrophes to indicate plural is so common that it has a name - the [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greengrocer's_apostrophe).