# How do you write "a class's constructor"?

Tags: orthography, possessives, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

I want to write this sentence:

> In a singleton pattern, a class's
>   constructor needs to be private
>   instead of public.

it is correct to write:

- a classes constructor
- a class' constructor
- a class's constructor
- a classes' constructor

Answer (score 10):

That would be *class'* or *class's*, but I would rather change the sentence to avoid that altogether.

Also, as it's a specific pattern that is applied to a specific class, it would be more correct to refer to *the pattern* and *the class* instead of *a pattern* and *a class*:

> In the singleton pattern, the constructor of the class needs to be private instead of public.

As the pattern is something that only is applied to a class, it can even be implied:

> In the singleton pattern, the constructor needs to be private instead of public.

Comment: Poor singleton! It is (indirectly) associated with "just avoid it altogether" even in the English Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 7):

*The Chicago Manual of Style, 14th edition* says:

> **6.19**: The possessive of singular nouns is formed by the addition of an apostrophe and an s [...]

There are a few exceptions listed later on, but they do not apply to a common noun ending in s (or ss).

Thus I say that

> a class's constructor

is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Both "a class' constructor" and "a class's constructor" are accepted as correct. More recent English use stylistic guides show preference for the "a class's constructor" use.