# How to write of process? Is it process' or process's?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

Can I write output of process as process'/process's output? How to use apostrophe in words ending with two ss like boss, actress, goddess, process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you write "a class's constructor"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15609/how-do-you-write-a-classs-constructor) The usual rule-of-thumb is to _choose_ the 's variant if you add an extra syllable when you pronounce the possessive.

Comment: Well, first of all, you should only use the apostrophe-S possession construction for human possessors. Non-human possessors, as a rule, take the _of_ construction.