# How do we pronounce "others'"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronouns, possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

I know that we pronounce "someone else's" as "someone else sus."
I'm wondering how do we pronounce *others'*.

Is it pronounced *others*, "others sus," or "other sus"?

Comment: "else sus"?  Who are you who put _three_ "s"s in the pronunciation of "else's"?

For me, it's "elsiz".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference in pronunciation among *others*, *other's*, and *others'*. They are pronounced the same as *others*.

Comment: +1 (It is interesting to learn that *others* is pronounced the same as *others*!)

Comment: @Cerberus. Umm... I think that was _others'_ (with the apostrophe). _others_ all the same, but not really _others'_.

Comment: @Tragicomic: I was teasing a bit: if you read Rob's answer literally, he says that *others* is pronounced the same as *others*.