# Dogs' or dogs's?

Tags: possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Me and a friend are wondering whether the right form of the possessive for the plural of a word (say dog) would be dogs' or dogs's

Example sentence:

> Those dogs' water bowls are empty

or

> Those dogs's water bowls are empty

Also, could you please clear up the use of the possessive on words both singular and plural which end with the letter 's'?