# What do you call a 'noun' with a (s) suffix e.g. parent(s)?

Tags: single-word-requests, parenthetical-plural

Is there a term for use of a combined singular / plural like  *parent(s)*?

For example:

> Do not assume there are two parents when you pen the letter regarding baby Bob;
>   use _____ instead.

or

> use the _____ approach instead?

I am not asking if *parent(s)* is good style - that is separate issue.
I have seen a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52244/how-do-you-make-a-word-like-parents-possessive) asking how to add a possessive `'s` to it but that is separate problem.
I googled for this but am not sure what to even search for.

Comment: **Optional plural**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many sites refer to this convention as the ***parenthetical plural***.

For example, at the [Grammarphobia Blog](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/04/parenthetical-plurals.html), the [American Medical Association](http://www.amamanualofstyle.com/view/10.1093/jama/9780195176339.001.0001/med-9780195176339-div2-282), and the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Plurals/faq0003.html).

[This site](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2010/04/put-the-tickets-in-the-envelopes-.html) discusses the merit of "parenthetical plural," and points out that

> *The Gregg Reference Manual* calls them "plural endings in parentheses."

You might also find them called ***optional plurals***.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I couldn't seem to come up with the right search criteria to track this down.