# Apostrophe position for plural possessive

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Which of these two are correct?

> Ada and Julia are **girl's** names.

or

> Ada and Julia are **girls'** names.

Comment: Both are correct. @Helpful was helpful indeed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Comment: @Ronan My question is different. "girl's" is a singular noun which does not end in the letter s. If this can be answered with common references, I'd love to see a reference that addresses this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use "girls' names" in this instance. If just one name is mentioned, the apostrophe goes inside:

> Ada is a girl's name.
>   Julia is a girl's name.

With more than one name mentioned, the apostrophe would go after the *s*.

Answer (score 1):

The possession - with how you've written it - doesn't make sense.

Because in this case "girl" is acting more as an adjective, I would write it as:

`Ada and Julia are girl's names.`

However, if Ada and Julia were the names of specific girls, say:

`Ada and Julia are *the* girls' names.`

Perhaps less confusing for this specific situation, if you want to avoid apostrophe use at all:

`Ada and Julia are girly names.`

Comment: +1 However, 'girly (or girlie) names' is odd; *girls names* with suitable apostrophe is common.

Comment: Or possibly 'Ada and Julia are girl-names'.

Comment: James and John are boyy names?  boy-y?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> Ada and Julia are names of girls.

for plural possessives in a sentence to avoid this issue altogether.

> There is another way around this problem of klunky possessives: using the "of phrase" to show possession. For instance, we would probably say the "constitution of Illinois," as opposed to "Illinois' (or Illinois's ??) constitution." ([Source](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm))

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of something to do with the apostrophes, I can't actually reproduce [the relevant NGrams usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20girl%27s%20names,are%20girls%27%20names,are%20boy%27s%20names,are%20boys%27%20names,are%20boy%27s%20toys,are%20boys%27%20toys&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,are%20girls%20%27%20names;,c0;.t1;,are%20boys%20%27%20names;,c0;.t1;,are%20boys%20%27%20toys;,c0) here, but if you follow that link it should be obvious OP's first usage *(**girl's**)* effectively doesn't exist by comparison with the "standard" version *(**girls'**)*.

Notice that I included ***toys*** as well as ***names*** in that first chart. Looking at the same construction using singular forms, it's obvious *writers* place the possessive apostrophe so as to make the plurality of the "adjectival noun" *(**girl, boy**)* agree with the actual noun being modified *(**name, toy**)*.

Of course, those preferences are purely a matter of orthography, since both versions would be identical in "real" language (speech) anyway. I think it's much more interesting to look at contexts where *all* native speakers (not just rule-obsessed writers) have to make the choice...

> Singular noun...
>    1: [*"It's a man's world"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20a%20man%27s%20world%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    2: [*"Where's the men's room?"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20a%20man%27s%20world%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20men%27s%20room%22&tbm=bks)
>    Plural noun...
>    3: [*"He believes that man's interests are asocial"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20a%20man%27s%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1971,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#lr=lang_en&q=%22man%27s%20interests%20are%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1971,cd_max:2000,lr%3alang_1en)
>    4: [*"Do you sell men's gloves?"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20a%20man%27s%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1971,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22men%27s%20gloves%22&tbm=bks)

Where 2 and 3 are the [odd **men** out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odd%20man%20out) (couldn't resist that! :) in that the plurality of the adjective and noun differ. I can only assume 2 is because *men's rooms*, [*men's clubs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20a%20man%27s%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1971,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22men%27s%20clubs%22&tbm=bks), and the [*Wimbledon men's final*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20a%20man%27s%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1971,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22Wimbledon%20men%27s%20final%22&tbm=bks) are so closely associated with *multiple* men that we depart from general principle. And 3 was the best example I could come up with, because it's so unusual - ***man*** there is really *mankind*, so in the minds of most speakers it's a collective plural noun anyway.