# Grammar with possessive plural

Tags: punctuation, possessives

How do you write "the clients (plural) needs? Is it the clients' needs?

Example sentence: "I utilized interpersonal skills to identify the clients' needs." Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in “‑s”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Answer (score 2):

> I utilized interpersonal skills to identify the clients' needs

Yes, this is grammatically correct. You put the apostrophe **after the word in plural** (i.e. clients) to indicate possession:

> To show *plural possession*, simply put an apostrophe after the **s**.
>
> **Correct**: guys' night out (guy + s + apostrophe)
>
> Incorrect: guy's night out (implies only one guy)
>
> **Correct**: two actresses' roles (actress + es + apostrophe)
>
> Incorrect: two actress's roles

(http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The ' comes after the plural word. In this case

**clients' needs