# Shays' Rebellion or Shays's Rebellion?

Tags: grammatical-number

On khan academy, it is Shays's. However on wikipedia, it is written Shays'. I am confused as to which one is grammatically correct. Thanks!

Comment: Well it's named after a man named Shays, not after multiple people named Shay, so I'd go with Shays's, myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Comment: Yes, thank you!