# Is " Princesses' " correct and how would it be pronounced?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

From my understanding:

" Princess " is the singular form

" Princess' " is the possessive form pronounced with an -es in the end

" Princesses " is the plural form which is pronounced in a similar manner

If I refer to the doll of a princess, it should be "Princess' Doll"(?)

But what if there were many princesses having dolls? Would I say "Princesses' Dolls?" (As Princess-is-is)? Or would the second "es" be silent?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you for the quick reply! Is there a specific rule for this? Would you say " Parents' " as "Parents-es" or just "Parent's"?

Comment: I would use _princess's doll_ in the singular. _Parents'_ is pronounced without an extra syllable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s) Although I seem to remember liking an answer by @tchrist  somewhere here a lot better. There remain anomalies, but these are rare and arcane;  basic research is missing here. For the singular possessive, like Kate I'd use 'princess's doll' to reflect the three syllables I'd use (eg for _Princess Anne's doll_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An apostrophe isn't used in *place* of an *s* if the *s* sound is spoken. If you hear an *s* sound (either unvoiced or voiced) at the end, write an *s* after the apostrophe.

So, the singular possessive is *princess's*, the plural nominative is *princesses*, and the plural possessive is *princesses'*. All of these are pronounced exactly the same way.

Most nouns ending in an *s* sound behave this way. For example, the forms for the word *bass* (the musical instrument) are *bass's*, *basses* and *basses'*, all pronounced exactly the same way.

However, irregular plurals form their possessive the same way as singular nouns. For example, the possessives of *children* and *mice* are *children's* and *mice's*, not *children'* and *mice'*.

There's also at least one irregular singular possessive: the possessive of the name *Jesus* is usually taken to be *Jesus'* (which is pronounced like *Jesus*, not like *Jesus's*) instead of *Jesus's*.

Comment: If talking about the fish, the simple plural is *bass*, whereas when talking about two or more species it is *basses*. Or so I've always thought; I'm not a fisherman, though I am a bassist. +1 though, good answer.

Comment: Your first statement is only commonly the case. Some styles, although not many, still use only an apostrophe. Also, even if the possessive of a noun ending with an *s* has only an apostrophe, that doesn't mean it's always pronounced like it's spelled. For example, I've often heard people pronounce *Jesus'* (when it's spelled that way) as *Jesus's*.

Comment: @nnnnnn Whoops, I forgot that fish are special!

Comment: What about 'my boss's car'? I've always been pronouncing it 'my bossiz ca:(r)'.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Yep, that pronunciation looks right.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up for me @ Tanner Swett and @Jasson Bassford, I've been having this doubt for a while now and I'm glad I asked here.