# Bare genitives: written vs spoken forms

Tags: grammar, possessives, speech

Page 1595 of the CambridgeGEL reads

> In writing *the bare genetive* has the form of an apostrophe at
> the end of the word: *dogs’*. **In speech it has no realisation at
> all** [...]; an optional bare genitive is found in certain types of
> proper names, where it is more likely *in writing than in speech*.
>
> It's obligatory with plural nouns ending in s, regular or irregular.
> Nouns like *species* which have identical singular and plural forms
> with final *s* take it in the singular as well as the
> plural, **and in writing** this will apply to nouns like *chassis*
> too.
>
> *The bare genitive* is the only possibility in fixed
> phrases with *sake* : *for convenience’ sake* has **a spoken /s/** but
> not written *s*.

As is clear, there are several contradictions in this page.

According to the text, the singular *species* (ˈspiːʃiːz —some speakers pronounce the singular with -ɪz, the plural with -iːz) also takes a bare genitive, **species'**, unlike the example given by the author in the same page **quiz's** (which follows the usual rule). Therefore, one cannot never know whether **species'** refers to the singular or plural.

Furthermore, **chassis'** for both the singular /ˈʃæsi/ and plural /ˈʃæsiz/; why not the usual rule for the singular one **chassis's** /ˈʃæsiz/?

Must bare genitives be divided into spoken and written forms? Otherwise, what characteristics define *bare genitives*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Comment: The rules the CGEL gives for *convenience'(s) sake* and *chassis'(s)* are not followed universally. The rules for spoken bare genitives were different in the past, and *convenience' sake* is a frozen form from when the genitive didn't change the pronunciation of the word *convenience*.

Comment: "chassis" is a special case. It comes from French. In the singular, the final "s" is silent. In the plural or genitive, it is sounded as "z".

Comment: @chaslyfromUK The singular _species_ (ˈspiːʃ iːz —some speakers pronounce the singular with -ɪz, the plural with -iːz) also takes a bare genitive, _species'_, unlike the example given by the author in the same page **quiz's** (which follows the usual rule). Therefore, one cannot never know whether  species' refers to the singular or plural.
Furthermore, ....in writing this will apply to nouns like _chassis_ too (that is, **chassis'** for both the singular /ˈʃæs i/ and plural /ˈʃæsiz/; why not the usual rule for the singular one **chassis's** /ˈʃæsiz/?

Comment: **Everything** has to be divided into spoken and written. Spoken English has no punctuation, to begin with, so there's no difference between plural and singular possessives. That's strictly printing nonsense, like the difference between _there, their,_ and _they're_, which are strictly identical in English, except when printed.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was referring to a name such as Descartes /deɪˈkɑːrt/, + **-'(s)**?

Comment: @PeterShor would you always pronounce _James’_ vs _James's_  as **dʒeɪmz** vs **ˈdʒeɪmzəz** respectively. Or rather _James’_ could also be **ˈdʒeɪmzəz**.

Comment: Well, there's always a problem with names like _Epimenides_. His motto -- 'Man is the measure of all things', in English -- might be referenced in print with an apostrophe alone, or with an apostrophized _s_, though I've never heard it used with any other pronunciation than the name, which already contains an /s/ and continually absorbs any added suffixation. As for _Descartes_, if one is speaking English one may pronounce it in a number of ways. There certainly is nothing fixed about its genitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler According to LPD, "With proper names ending in a sibilant, usage varies. Usually, the possessive is pronounced regularly, though the spelling may vary: _Jones’ , Jones’s_ **dʒoʊnzəz**. Less commonly, the possessive ending is unpronounced (**dʒoʊnz**), but the corresponding spelling is then _Jones’_  "

Comment: Note that 'sibilant' is a phonetic term, not a description of any letter. And, yes, if the proper name is **pronounced** with a sibilant at the end, adding the possessive `{-Z₂}` normally adds a syllable (with an epenthetic shwa). _Jones's_ (or for that matter, _the Joneses_, with plural `{-Z₁}` as well) is a good example. But _Descartes's_ /'dekartsəz/ is not, and neither is _Epimenides's /ɛpə'mɛnədizəz/_. Too many unstressed syllables at the end.

Comment: @JohnLawler what about **you(r) guys'(s)**? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_guys#Usage_notes

Answer (score 1):

The CGEL example is misleading. The authors have chosen not to emphasise that “convenience” ends in a sibilant - the /s/ sound: “for God’s sake” is quite normal as “God” does not end in a sibilant. Further, they make an unsupported statement *“for convenience’ sake* has a spoken /s/ but not written s.” This cannot be justified. It is important for students to understand that there is no final authority in English and there is no justification for the absolute claim.

OED

> II. for the sake of (also †for sake of); **for (one's, a thing's) sake**. In the latter of these forms, the word which precedes *sake* is a possessive (noun or pronoun); but down to the middle of the 19th c. the ***'s*** of the possessive of common or abstract nouns was very commonly omitted (doubtless owing to the difficulty of pronouncing the two sibilants in succession) […]. The omission of the **'s** is now obsolete, but it is still not uncommon to **write**  for conscience sake, for goodness sake, for righteousness sake, etc., without the apostrophe which is ordinarily used to mark the possessive **of words ending in a sibilant.**

That latter remark is now, itself, outdated and, at least, the apostrophe should be included – the ***s*** is usually optional in words ending in a sibilant.

Comment: what about **you(r) guys'(s)**? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_guys#Usage_notes

Comment: What exactly bothers you about "you(r) guys'(s)"?

Comment: _guys_ is plural, yet we find **you guys's**

Comment: We find it in substandard English.

Comment: Basically, we figured too many "s" sounds clustered at the end did not make for a pleasant listening or speaking journey.

Comment: @GJC *what about you(r) guys'(s)?* "You" in "you guys" is a demonstrative adjective/determiner. "You" indicates the set of guys being referred to. **Your guys** does not exist on its own. **Your guys'** - "your" is a personal possessive adjective/determiner, and guys' is a plural possessive pronoun. In **Your guys' hats** **Your** and **guys'** are both determiners/adjectives.